# How to call rimraf in a loop in gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a gulp file, a am trying to "rimraf" multiple directories in a loop:

```
gulp.task('clean:dest', function(cb) {
    for(var i = 0; i < config.dest_dirs.length; i++){
        console.log('cleaning: ' + config.dest_dirs[i]);
        rimraf(config.dest_dirs[i] + '/*', cb);
    }
    console.log('Clean dest dir task completed');
});
```

After the first call, the next ones generate the error:

```
Error: task completion callback called too many times
```

Can I set this up so that I can make the calls Async, but wait for all processes to complete before returning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`async.parallel()`](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#parallel) executes multiple asynchronous functions in parallel and calls the `cb` callback only when all of them have finished:

```
var async = require('async');

gulp.task('clean:dest', function(cb) {
  async.parallel(config.dest_dirs.map(function(dir) {
    return function(done) {
      console.log('cleaning: ' + dir);
      rimraf(dir + '/*', done);
    }
  }), cb);
});
```

Also note that by doing `rimraf(config.dest_dirs[i] + '/*')` as you do in your example you're only deleting the contents of each directory, but not the directory itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to remove multiple directories you might be better off concatenating them all to a string:

```
gulp.task('clean:dest', function(cb) {
    var allDirs = config.dest_dirs.join(','); // "myDir1,myDir2"
    var glob = '{' + allDirs + '}'; // "{myDir1,myDir2}"
    rimraf(glob);
    console.log('Clean dest dir task completed');
});
```